# Jenkins timer filter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to  write a plugin. My main problem is suppose that I have a pipeline ,and when I click on it in build history tab I see that  there are many build . I want to see that which build is runned by timer and which one is runned by others? Dou you know a plugin do that? Otherwise, can you show me how can I write this kind of plugin?

I could not find a plugin doing that

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins builds always have a trigger cause mentioned in the build page as well as the console output; you don't need to use any plugins for this as it is an in-built feature. If you go to either the build page or console log, you will see the build cause at the very top (started by SCM change, started by user, started by upstream job, started by timer, etc...).

For example:

[image: console output]